# Google map not displaying in magento

Tags: magento, google-maps-api-3

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
</script>
```

have added this is the head.phtml

and

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        initialize();
});
</script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
```

placed this in my phtml

it seems to be putting lots of values in the div, so i know the script is working but nothing is being displayed, could anyone point out the mistake and guide me to a correct direction???

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the call to initialize in `document.ready()`, use Google's own event listener instead:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: where do i place it in the head.phtml?

Comment: well that didn't help, most of the divs coming due to the script are still hidden remains hidden

Answer (score 0):

Hello check following code may be help you

> < script type="text/javascript"
>   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
>
> < script type="text/javascript"
>   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&sensor=true">
>
> < script type="text/javascript">
>
> function initialize() {
>
> var latitude = parseFloat("22.258652"); // Latitude get from above
>   variable
>
> var longitude = parseFloat("71.1923805"); // Longitude from same
>
> var latlngPos = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
>
> ```
>  var mapOptions = {
>   center: latlngPos,
>   zoom: 10,
>   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
> };
>  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
> ```
>
> var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlngPos, map: map,
>   title: "test" });
>
> }
>
> < script>

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and added a surrounding div with a fixed size as per this answer, worked for me. 
[Map isn't showing on Google Maps JavaScript API v3 when nested in a div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349476/map-isnt-showing-on-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-when-nested-in-a-div-tag)