# Map isn't showing on Google Maps JavaScript API v3 when nested in a div tag

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to put the `div` tag that shows the map (`<div id="map-canvas"></div>`) inside another `div`, but it doesn't show the map that way. Is it a CSS or a JavaScript problem? Or is it just the way the API works?

Here's my code with the the nested `div`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> <!-- ommiting this div will show the map -->
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Add `style="width:100%; height:100%;"` to the div see what that does

not to the `#map_canvas` but the main div

example

```
<body>
    <div style="height:100%; width:100%;">
         <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

There are some other answers on here the explain why this is necessary

Comment: yes assigning dimensions to map parent container fixed it, thanks !

Answer (score 50):

The problem is with percentage sizing.  You are not defining the size of the parent div (the new one), so the browser can not report the size to the Google Maps API.  Giving the wrapper div a specific size, or a percentage size if the size of its parent can be determined, will work.

See [this explanation from Mike Williams' Google Maps API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm):

> If you try to use style="width:100%;height:100%" on your map div, you get a map div that has zero height. That's 
>   because the div tries to be a percentage of the size of the `<body>`, but by default the `<body>` has an indeterminate 
>   height.
>
> There are ways to determine the height of the screen and use that number of pixels as the height of the map div, 
>   but a simple alternative is to change the `<body>` so that its height is 100% of the page. We can do this by 
>   applying style="height:100%" to both the `<body>` and the `<html>`. (We have to do it to both, otherwise the 
>   `<body>` tries to be 100% of the height of the document, and the default for that is an indeterminate height.)

Add the 100% size to html and body in your css

```
    html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Add it inline to any divs that don't have an id:

```
<body>
  <div style="height:100%; width: 100%;"> 
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 23):

I solved this problem with:

```
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">
                 <div id="map-canvas"></div>
     </div>
```

Comment: damn, that absolute fix this, lost two hours of life :D

Answer (score 16):

Give initial height of div and specify height in percentage in your style;

```
#map {
   height: 100%;
}

<div id="map" style="clear:both; height:200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

In my case I was getting the grey background and it turned out to be inclusion of a zoom value in the map options.  Yup, makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

Wizard

Have you tried setting the height and width of the extra div, I know that on a project I am working on JS won't put anything in the div unless I have the height and width already set.

I used your code and hard coded the height and width and it shows up for me and without it doesn't show.

```
<body>
    <div style="height:500px; width:500px;"> <!-- ommiting the height and width will not show the map -->
         <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would recommend either hard coding it in or assigning the div an ID and then add it to your CSS file.

Answer (score 4):

I just want to add what worked for me, I added height and width to both divs and used bootstrap to make it responsive

```
   <div class="col-lg-1 mapContainer">
       <div id="map"></div>
   </div>

   #map{
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
   }
   .mapContainer{
        height:200px;
        width:100%
   }
```

in order for `col-lg-1` to work add bootstrap reference located
[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

Understand this has been solved, but the solution provided above might not work in all situation.

For my case,

```
<div style="height: 490px; position:relative; overflow:hidden">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```