# wordpress with google map API doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-maps

i am using PHP and MYSQL on WordPress with Google Map API where i am retrieving data from the MYSQL database and display markers on the Google Map based on the coordinates retrieved from the database.

the problem is that noting is displayed in the web page, can anyone tell me where is the error in my code?

## code:

```
<?php
        /*
        Template Name: MAP2
        */

        get_header();
  ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Markers</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

     var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91722, 151.23064),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var icons = {
          parking: {
            icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
          },
          library: {
            icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
          },
          info: {
            icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
          }
        };

        function addMarker(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
          });
        }

        var features = 
          {
            <?php
            global $wpdb;
              $prependStr ="";
              foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM site_coordinates2") as $key => $row) 
              {
                  $latitude = $row->latitude;
                  $longitude = $row->longitude;
                  $info = $row->siteID;
             echo $prependStr;
           ?>
    {

    position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude ?>, <?php echo $latitude ?>),
    type: '<?php echo $info;?>'
   }
   <?php
   $prependStr =",";
   }


  ?>
}
    </script>

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***************callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem from setting the height. See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349476/map-isnt-showing-on-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-when-nested-in-a-div-tag)

But in my cases, set the specific pixel to map div. Like this `#map {min-height: 600px;}`

Comment: i did change the height to 300px but still nothing is shown

Comment: I tested your codes but it's okay to show maps. Did you ever use "&" after "auth key"?

Comment: Add "&" to just before "callback"?

Comment: that is what i did
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=********&callback=initMap">

Comment: I think your "php" code has some error. Try remove "php" codes and run app.

Comment: Can you open a chrome dev tools and any console messages?

Comment: i did not understand your question

Comment: If you use chrome browser then press "F12" and reload the page and see console tab. If page has any error messages are shown

Comment: i tried your answer and it displays 2 errors :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
*********************
Uncaught Xc
message:
"initMap is not a function"
name:
"InvalidValueError

Comment: At the right of syntax error message show, clickable line number show. Click it and check javascript syntax error.

Comment: ichanged the place of the script that includes the google map API and API key.
now it displays these errors:
(index):140 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

Uncaught Xc {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Xc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…*********&callback=initMap:137:73"}

Comment: it was a missing brakets .... now it display the map  but o think i have a problem in the php because when i uncomment it the map doesn't work

Comment: That's nice display the map. To find the php code problems, browser's view page source (mouse right-click on page) then check your php code compiled.