# Google Maps displays as thin line in Bootstrap column

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

All the code is here and you can run it locally, just open up qibla.html:

https://github.com/readyready15728/qibla-finder

I tried another suggestion about getting the map to display here:

[Map isn't showing on Google Maps JavaScript API v3 when nested in a div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349476/map-isnt-showing-on-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-when-nested-in-a-div-tag)

I can see it in my Bootstrap example but it's just a very thin line for me. I'm really not sure where to go from here. What do I do to preserve relative sizing and still get it to display? Pixels work but I want it to be responsive.

EDIT: Here is the JSFiddle someone requested: https://jsfiddle.net/ygsfeba9/

And here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1 class="text-center">Interactive Qibla Finder</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Blah blah blah, here's where the controls and output will go.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
    zoom: 1
  });
}
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDAnAdXjgiEX08RLBbMle9X_WWN4BzNHBg&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Create a minimal example.

Comment: You have a minimal example in the code that's on GitHub

Comment: It's all there...

Comment: I know, but I have to clone the repo and then have access to the example. Put some effort into creating a fiddle or plunkr.

Comment: Alright I'll do that

Comment: Tried creating a JSFiddle but console gives me the error "initMap is not a function". Is typing git clone really onerous?

Comment: Never mind, found a workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/ygsfeba9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best outcome using relative units appears to be with the following CSS:

```
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
}
```

Alter vertical height units to taste.

Answer (score 3):

You should not have `#map` position set to `absolute`. If you do so, you will have to make its parent element `col-md-8` position relative, and have height property to `500px` or so.

```
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygsfeba9/1/)

Comment: Is there any way to have height relative?

Comment: As in a percentage

Comment: There is `vh` unit which depends on the viewport. `#map` contains an absolute element (created by the SDK).

Comment: That looks pretty useful actually