# Google Maps code does not work on my file but works elsewhere

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

The below code actually works and shows the map with correct location and marker (the div with id="map", scripts with javascript function and API) when I put the code into another html document without any other content.

The problem now is that for some reason, when I am using the exact same codes for Google Maps with working API in this HTML, the map does not show up at all.

Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title>-</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
       /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
      #map {
        width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
        max-width:450px;
       }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
    ...

      <div class="row">
        ...

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script>
        // Initialize and add the map
        function initMap() {
        // The location of company
        var freshlocation = {lat: 1.337344, lng: 103.912835};
        // The map, centered at company
        var map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 7, center: freshlocation});
        // The marker, positioned at company
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: freshlocation, map: map});
        }
      </script>
      <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap">
      </script>
...

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am wondering if it has something to do with some of the codes in head, such as importing fonts or bootstrap, or the position of the maps div, like putting the map into container or row class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map isn't showing on Google Maps JavaScript API v3 when nested in a div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349476/map-isnt-showing-on-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-when-nested-in-a-div-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have managed to figure out the answer. Setting the height of the map div solved the problem.